# How can I detect programming language's error messages from text?

Tags: java, c, exception

I am conducting sentiment analysis on software developers' comments on github. Usually they tend to write the error messages and exceptions within the comment.

My question is how to remove these error/exception messages ?

For example:

Comment:

"
I got this error today: Bad Gateway (502) and 500 (Internal Server Error).
Will you update the code to not raise the error and show a logger warning/error instead of the traceback?

Trakt is having a lot of issues lately.

```
:~/SickRage/Logs$ grep -Ri "Server Error"
sickbeard.log.1:traktException: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway
sickbeard.log.1:traktException: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
sickbeard.log.1:traktException: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
sickbeard.log:traktException: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway
sickbeard.log:traktException: 520 Server Error: Origin Error

sickbeard.log.1:  File "/home/pi/SickRage/sickbeard/traktChecker.py", line 48, in run
sickbeard.log.1:  File "/home/pi/SickRage/sickbeard/traktChecker.py", line 127, in updateShows
sickbeard.log.1:    watchlist = self.trakt_api.traktRequest("user/watchlist/shows.json/%APIKEY%/%USER%")
sickbeard.log.1:  File "/home/pi/SickRage/lib/trakt/trakt.py", line 39, in traktRequest
sickbeard.log.1:    raise traktException(e.message)
sickbeard.log.1:traktException: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway
sickbeard.log.1:2014-11-29 14:16:33 DEBUG    TRAKTCHECKER :: Starting new thread: TRAKTCHECKER
sickbeard.log.1:2014-11-29 14:16:33 DEBUG    TRAKTCHECKER :: Starting trakt show watchlist check
sickbeard.log.1:2014-11-29 14:16:35 DEBUG    TRAKTCHECKER :: No shows found in your watchlist, aborting watchlist update
sickbeard.log.1:2014-11-29 14:16:35 DEBUG    TRAKTCHECKER :: Starting trakt episode watchlist check
sickbeard.log.1:2014-11-29 14:17:03 DEBUG    TRAKTCHECKER :: Traceback (most recent call last):
sickbeard.log.1:  File "/home/pi/SickRage/sickbeard/traktChecker.py", line 49, in run
sickbeard.log.1:  File "/home/pi/SickRage/sickbeard/traktChecker.py", line 162, in updateEpisodes
sickbeard.log.1:    watchlist = self.trakt_api.traktRequest("user/watchlist/episodes.json/%APIKEY%/%USER%")
sickbeard.log.1:  File "/home/pi/SickRage/lib/trakt/trakt.py", line 39, in traktRequest
sickbeard.log.1:    raise traktException(e.message)
sickbeard.log.1:traktException: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
```

"

Required: Remove the exception part from the comment.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You'll have to be much more specific about what exactly you want to achieve to receive any useful answers or even comments. As a minimum, you'll need to post a sample of comments (or links to comments) and an explanation of what you want to remove / leave alone. It also helps if you explain the approach(es) you've tried and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: You could use stack overflow to help classify the error messages by their tags.

Comment: @laszlok  Thx, I have updated it accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Think of a RegEx pattern that Matches those exceptions then use a RegEx replace statement to replace this pattern with "". The hard part here will be to determine the pattern of those exceptions you probably have to do some datamining to do this